# C++ Pointer Question

Tags: c++, string

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

main:

```
    Book* test = new Book;

char* end = "HelloThere";

test->reverseCString(end);



char* Book::reverseCString(char* woot)
{
    char* end = woot;

    while ( *end )
    {
        end++;
    }
    end--;
    // Now we end is at the last letter
    // and woot is at the first
    // now we swap them
    char temp; 
    while ( woot < end ) 
    {
        temp = *woot;
        *woot++ = *end; <--- Problem here during runtime.
        *end-- = temp;      
    }
    return woot;
}
```

Comment: Problem? What kind of problem? Is there an error message or any additional information you can give us?

Comment: How are you calling this function?  Is woot even writable?

Comment: Also, technically this has UB when called on an empty string. You aren't allowed to even create a pointer one before the beginning of an array, let alone compare it to another pointer. I very much doubt that's your problem, though.

Comment: @Merlyn: Stop it.  Pointers are part of the C++ language even if you don't like it.  And string literals are handled subtly differently in C++ from C.

Comment: @RoR, Ben: Sorry about that.  Maybe it's time I take a break...

Comment: @RoR: @Merlyn does have a point, this isn't a very traditional C++ approach to this problem.  If you're trying to learn C++, you should try to write a function that works on a `std::string`, and eventually your own version of `std::reverse` that works on a variety of containers.  But either of those is somewhat more advanced than your question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* end = "HelloThere";
```

String literal "HelloThere" is located in the read only location and is not modifiable.

```
char* Problems::reverseCString(char* woot)
{
    // Both woot and end are pointing to the string literal stored in 
    // read only location.
}
```

Comment: @RoR - With the above hint given, rewrite the logic.

Comment: @RoR gcc4.3 would have complained about this: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

Answer (score 2):

**`const`** `char* end = "HelloThere";`

There, fixed that for you.

Now, figure out how to make a copy of your string somewhere you can write to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
char end[] = "HelloThere";
```

Now end is writable, and you can reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged C++, why not use the C++ standard library?

```
std::string s = "Hello There";
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
```